# Moving sites from one server to another

Tags: migration, content-deployment, infrastructure

I am using SharePoint Server Enterprise 2007 with Windows Server 2008 Enterprise. I have a site collection which is using 3 types of sites publishing portal/wiki/blog. I want to move the template (e.g. master pages) and data from one server to another. Server domain names and IP address are different.

What is the suggested way to do this task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the content is in a content database with no other content, you could backup the content db and move it and then attach it in the new farm.

If it is not, you can use the command line

`stsadm.exe -o backup -url [yoursitecollectionurl] -filename [filename]`

to back the file up on the current server, then copy the file to the new server and use the command line

`stsadm.exe -o restore -url [newsitecollectionurl] -filename [filename]`

to restore the file to the new location. One caveat to this is that you must have the new web application created on the new server farm. You don't necessarily have to have the new site collection created. However, if you have created a blank site in the same url that you want the new site collection to be restored to, you will want to add `-overwrite` to the command line.

Comment: 1. Do you mean stsadm command cannot move content in content database and we have to move content database manually? 2. could you command backup/restore custom master page and css files correctly?

Comment: @George2: The stsadm command Lori describes will handle the master page and CSS files.

Comment: No, the command cannot move the content database was just giving you two options to move it. If you use the backup/restore, it will move the content into a new content db on the new farm.

Comment: 1. Should I backup/restore DB at first or executing stsadm first? 2. When backup/restore DB, should I use attach/detach or use backup/restore in SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: The options are mutually exclusive, you can either move the contentdb OR use the command line. If you use the command line, you don't need to touch the content db. If you decide to move the contentdb instead, I prefer to use a SQL backup/restore method to move it. Makes falling back to the original easier.

Comment: Sorry Lori. I am a bit confused since English is not my native language. You mean I only need to use stsadm, correct? (and using content database backup/restore is another alternative solution?)

Comment: Actually, my major concern is, in the source MOSS 2007 server, I am using SQL Server 2005 Express, and in the destination product MOSS 2007 server, I am using SQL Server 2008 Enterprise. Any issue dealing with different database version when using stsadm to migrate?

Comment: George, you are correct that using stsadm is all you need to use. To my knowledge, using stsadm will not be affected by the difference in the databases.

Comment: Cool, I will have a try. :-)

Comment: One thing to add: If you want to use stsadm -o backup/restore be aware that both servers (source and destination) must run the same version of SharePoint. This mean on both servers have to be equipped with the same service packs and cumulative updates.